# Identify your own string-object for large strings?

Tags: c#, string

Maybe this sounds weird, but the idea is to define a class, say `LargeString`, which **acts like a string**, except it should not create a new reference by calling the '+=' operator.

So I could use this `LargeString` for Concatenations, rather than the `StringBuilder`-Class.

This should look something like this:

```
LargeString s1 = "someLongString1";
LargeString s2 = "someLongString2";
LargeString s3 = s1 + s2;
s3 += "someLongString3"
```

Then the last line **should not create** a new reference.
Is this somehow possible with overloadable operators or other tricks?

**Note:** I know I could achieve this easily by creating a class with a local
   Stringbuilder member, but I would really like find a more beautiful
   way.

Comment: AFAIK, that's totally impossible.  (if you want precisely that syntax)

Comment: Note 1 is not correct. You could provide an implicit conversion from `string` to `LargeString`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Cheers. Just removed it.

Comment: All this to avoid `stringBuilder.Append()`?

Comment: What does this class do that StringBuilder does not do?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "more aesthetic" than by wrapping a StringBuilder - a facade over StringBuilder seems like the obvious solution. Otherwise, you're faced with *re-implementing* StringBuilder's behaviour, aren't you? There's nothing "aesthetic" about that...

Comment: You guys are absolutely, 100% right about all.
I'm no enemy of StringBuilder. And I am well aware that to include StringBuilder is no big deal at all.
But I wondered if it was somehow possible to customize a string object, which fits better under certain circumstances than the normal one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# does not allow overloading the `=` operator or the `+=` operator. The `+=` operator will use any appropriate `+` operator, but will always perform `+` followed by `=`.

The only option would be to override the `+` operator to return the left instance, such as the following:

```
//Allows no copy +=
public static operator +(LongString left, LongString right)
{
    left.Add(right);
    return left;
}

//Allows assignment of string to LongString
public static implicit operator LongString(string original)
{
    return new LongString(original);
}
```

But I would highly discourage doing this as it is not standard at all and will be confusing for anyone using it.

With regards to actual implementation, unless `StringBuilder` has a major flaw with your design you will probably want to wrap it for your base case.

Comment: +1: MSDN link - [Overloadable Operators(C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: +1: I like this answer so far. I will wait some more time and accept this, if nothing better occurs.

Comment: @FabianBigler: Just watch out since `a = b + c` will result in `a == b`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve `LargeString s1 = "test1"` you can use [implicit user-defined type conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and make it so that this will compile:

```
void Foo(string s)
{
}

LargeString largeString = "test";
Foo(largeString);
```

Comment: LargeString s3 = s1 + s2; is still a problem.  But LargeString could implement Append like StringBuilder does, and then implement your memory management how you like.  A list of other LargeString objects?